# What's the best way to append html tags to existing text?

Tags: javascript, office-js

I want to use the currently selected text in the office document to be replaced by the same selected text but surrounded with html. Effectively adding a hyperlink to the current selection.

I first read the text property of the selection

```
var objRange = objContext.document.getSelection();
objRange.load('text');
```

followed by

```
return objContext.sync().then(function(){
    var strSelection = objRange.text;
    objRange.insertHtml(
        "<a href='" + decodeURIComponent(strHyperlink) + "'>" + strSelection + "</a>", 
        Word.InsertLocation.replace
    );
    return objContext.sync().then(function(){
        objDialog.close();
    });
});
```

I need a sync to read the text and then another one to write the updated text back into the document after that I close a dialog. But this sometimes causes the html to get written into the document twice. Is there a better way of doing this instead of with double context syncs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, if you need to read the text and then write into a different context, you'll need two syncs. 
But you might take a look at the [Range.hyperlink](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/range) property, which is writeable. I don't know if it'll give you a way to avoid two syncs, but is intended for what you seem to be using `insertHtml` to do.

Comment: So if i understand you correctly, the second sync needs a different context?

Comment: No. You use the same context object through the whole Word.run.

Comment: I'm suggesting that instead of using insertHtml, you write your URL to the objRange.hyperlink property.